# How to integrate razor payment to the asp classic?

Tags: asp-classic, payment-gateway, razorpay

I have to integrate the razor payment to the asp classic and for this i have write the code for that is

```
 razamt=razamt*100
 dim options
 set options = server.createObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 options.add "amount", razamt
 options.add "receipt", "order_rcptid_11"
 options.add "currency", "INR"
 options.add "payment_capture", "0"
 **Order order = client.Order.Create(options)**
```

getting issue in star marked line client is not available and i have no idea how to solve this 
Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: `Order order = client.Order.Create(options)` looks like it's probably C# syntax. Are you trying to use a .NET library in an asp-classic app, or something? It's a bit unclear. Unless razorpay provides a ready-made client library for asp-classic, which is probably unlikely these days, you will need to write your own and make it send HTTP requests to their API.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using MSXML.ServerXMLHTTP, example

```
DataToSend = "amount=1&receipt=order_rcptid_11&currency=INR&payment_capture=0"

set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML6.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST","https://api.razorpay.com/v1/orders",false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xmlhttp.send DataToSend
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Write xmlhttp.responsexml.xml
Set xmlhttp = nothing
```